# ngRoute not working and recieving modulerr

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble with ngRoute. Everything looks to be spelled correctly, and I believe my syntax is correct. Pages are not routing and I am getting the injector:modulerr error.

Index.html:

```
<body ng-app='creativeBillingApp' >


<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
**<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>**
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/fastclick.js"></script>
```

routes.js

```
use strict';

var app = angular.module('creativeBillingApp', ['ngRoute']);


 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
     controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })

   .when('/carriers', {
     templateUrl: 'views/carriers.html',
     controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
 }])
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('creativeBillingApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ]);
```

complete index.html:

```
       <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app='creativeBillingApp' class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/themify-icons.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/animate.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/skins/palette.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/fonts/font.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/www/css/main.css"/>

<script src="bower_components/www/plugins/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->




  </head>
  <body>



      <!-- main content -->
          <div class="mainContainer" ng-view></div>
          <!-- /main content -->


    </section>

</div>

</script>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/plugins/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->





    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/offscreen.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/filters/reverse.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/account.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/user.js"></script>


    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
 </html>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
  GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/www/css/main.css.map 404 (Not Found)     (index):220
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module creativeBillingApp due to:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/routes.js:30:8
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869:17)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3788:37
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11)
at loadModules (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5)
at createInjector (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:11)
at doBootstrap (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1379:20)
at bootstrap (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1394:12)
at angularInit (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1307:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=creativeBillingApp…2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1307%3A5) angular.js:78
```

Comment: you create your app module twice

Comment: You are not having trouble with `ngRoute`. You are having trouble with something else. In order to determine what causes your error, please reference non-minified version of angular, load the page into the browser and post the error that you see there in the console.

Comment: you need to reference `angular-route.js`. The routing library that you are referencing is something different. Or you can start using it instead of `ngRoute`.

Comment: you posted two different versions of `index.html`. which one are you using? which one gives this error? The hardest thing of all is to find a black cat in a dark room, especially if there is no cat.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried using angular.ui.route thinking it was maybe angular-route that was the problem. I will switch it bak, now. the second index.html is the correct one getting the error above.

Comment: okay the error changed when i switched back to angular-route I have replaced the error message above for the correct one.

Comment: ok. what is line 30 in routes.js? Could you post that? : )

Comment: LINE 30! that was it. it asked for authentication before routing and I deleted the authentication scripts.... THANK YOU!

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than just the once.

Answer (score 1):

Your app name `creativeBillingApp` should be registered `one time`.

Remove the following line from `routes.php` and check

```
var app = angular.module('creativeBillingApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Since, `app` is a `global variable` and you can use it directly in `routes.js`

Note: `routes.js` should call after `app.js`

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/dZ9AY0qIXD7YJD1UAt3C?p=preview

Comment: or rather replace it with `var app = `angular.module('creativeBillingApp')`

Comment: @akonsu, yes, it means get the registered module.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I tried both removing it and replacing it with just angular.module('creativeBillingApp') and I am still receiving the same error. Where else am I registering creativeBillingApp? I have also reorganized my calls with routes.js coming after app.js, still no change in error.

Comment: @Lizajean it will be easier if you provide the text of the error

Comment: I have edited my code to match your demo and I am still getting the same error.

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=creativeBillingApp…Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A215)

Comment: Please use angular.js (non compressed version) and it is giving error somewhat little more info...pls try post the error here.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module creativeBillingApp due to:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/routes.js:30:8

Comment: you have missed to add a method in your controller scope...means, called it in template but not in controller..please post complete html page..